# What does this mean or what this is mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I'm learning English and generally used "what this is mean", but I see many using "what does this mean".
Is the way I speak incorrect or informal?

Comment: You will get answers on the English Language Learners site. We never use "What this is mean". "What does this mean?" is used as a question.

Answer (score 1):

Questions like the one you are asking about are constructed with a form of "to do" as an auxilliary verb, not with a form of "to be".

Let's look at a declarative sentence first:

> The cat eats.

To make this into a question that can be answered with yes or no, you use a form of "to do" as an auxilliary verb:

> Does the cat eat?

To make the declarative sentence into a question for further information, you also use a form of "to do" as an auxilliary verb:

> What does the cat eat?

So, in your case, the declarative sentence could be:

> This means that the cat is hungry.

and the question form would be

> What does this mean?

If you change the tense from simple present to present progressive, you already have a form of "to be" as an auxilliary verb in the declarative sentence:

> The cat is eating.

In this case, you can just use the form of "to be" to build a question, you don't need a form of "to do" as an additional auxilliary verb. So the question would be

> Is the cat eating?

But the sentence you asked about isn't in present progressive, it is in simple present. Because of that, you need a form of "to do" to build a question.